# Resize Image Proportionally on Orientation Change

Tags: android

I have a fragment inside an activity that consists of a `RelativeLayout`, an `ImageView` and a `TextView` having following layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/avaImage"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Available"
                android:textSize="26sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avaImage"
                android:layout_width="487dp"
                android:layout_height="238dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I'm setting the image source programatically:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.avaImage);
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.availability_green));
```

My question is, how can I shrink the image size so it fits in the screen in landscape mode, as well? Image shall be shrunk just enough to have the text appear within the bounds? This is what I want to achieve

Potrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

Comment: You can you  android:scaleType="fitCenter" in your imageview, and also remove your fix width and height.

Comment: I did try it with "fitCenter" in the imageview but it didn't help. What do I put as `width` and `height` if I remove the hard-coded values?

Comment: you can always handle this type of case by overriding onConfigurationChanged() method.

Comment: @santalu I did hard-code width and height on `onConfigurationChanged()` but the entire method didn't seem to work for me. Would appreciate if you could provide relevant code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your images shrunk. its set same image ration with center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avaImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Available" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why the `LinearLayout`? Can the same not be done with RelativeLayout?

Comment: @BasitSaeed you give you fix width and height Imageview in RelativeLayout they not work all resolution. This type code work in all resolution so its use LinearLayout.